# How to consistently Generate correct SHA-384 hash strings in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, security, hashcode

I'm trying to generate files then hash their contents and the append that hash at the end of the file content. For the has I am using SHA-384 and my hash function code is pasted below. The Issue is its not consistent in generating right Hash Strings, thus the hash and file contents end up invalid (Unmatched) for some files while valid for others. Is there anything I can do to resolve this? I'm using a third party application to read and validate the files thus I unfortunately cannot get their decoding function.

```
public static String hash384(byte[] inputBytes) throws Exception{
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            String hash;
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-384");
            messageDigest.update(inputBytes);
            byte[] digestedBytes = messageDigest.digest();
            hash = new String(digestedBytes, "windows-1251");
            return hash;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your problem probably comes from the char set encoding you are using to convert bytes to string, try using UTF-8 instead

Comment: Thanks for your contributoion, I have tried to use UTF-8 but it chunks down the characters to less than 48, the reason I'm using that one (windows-1251) is because it gives me 48 character hash which is what required by the decoding application..

Comment: Why are you converting to a `String` at all?  A digest is binary data, not text.  Its raw form is not well suited to being represented as a `String`, and you already have a nice `byte[]` representation of it that you could return.

Comment: Also, the input to your method is a little suspicious.  In the first place, it requires you to have the entire contents of the file in memory in that array.  That's awfully heavyweight if you must handle large files.  Additionally, it's not clear how you in fact obtain those input bytes.  Are you sure they exactly match the complete contents of the target file, byte for byte?

Comment: The input is are long text which is at least 300 characters long but can extend to much more, I convert the string to bytes by the String.getBytes() thus I get bytes as input data. The expected out should look like this: (h'6†¥ª‚ÿ¦áŽ
‰ÇKåqöØ«ltq®Ð¸]­<^[‹ŒÇ5B\˜ê‡Í<) which should be 48 characters long thus me converting the bytes to string in order for me to use Character sets, returning the bytes alone does not return the 48 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) from Apache's `commons-codec` module so that there are literally two line of code to write:

```
import static org.apache.commons.codec.digest.MessageDigestAlgorithms.SHA_384;
...
// digest
byte[] digest = new DigestUtils(SHA_384).digest(new File(<file path>));
// hex digest
String hdigest = new DigestUtils(SHA_384).digestAsHex(new File(<file path>));
```

Comment: Since the OP says that he gets the wanted result some of the time, I think it unlikely that he's trying to obtain a hexadecimal representation.  His original code would *never* do that.

Comment: Answer updated to accommodate non-hex representation as well.

Comment: @IllyaKysil the last option return a 96 character string, any idea on how I can turn that down to 48? Many thanks!

Comment: Both methods - `digest` and `digestHex` compute the same value but it is represented differently. `digestHex` represents each byte of result of `digest` as two hexadecimal digits, 2 digits per byte, 96 digits in total. The only way to turn it down to 48 **bytes** is to perform reverse transformation. But you already have that data - it's result of `digest`. Just skip the `new String(digestedBytes, "windows-1251");` as not all **bytes** can be represented as **characters** in the specified encoding.